# Swift + Parse - How to force app to refresh after logout

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiview, uiviewcontroller

How do I refresh all my UIViews to show the data for the new user.

(Scenario: User1 logs out and User2 logs in without closing the app.)

Right now I have a Logout button on my userVC. Upon pressing it the current user is logged out and the login view is presented. If a new user logs in the view dismisses and shows the userVC again. The userVC, because it was never refreshed keeps showing the data of the old user. (This is also true for all other VCs in this tabbed application.)

How do I get the views to reload their data? (Or redraw?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can achieve this, but the first thing you should do is add an ACL to your userdata so that User2 **does not have access** to User1's data! Security is something you *must* take seriously when handling data for multiple users.
More info: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security

If you log in a user, you could call a method for fetching the data. How is the data for your view retrieved? Whatever code you're using to fetch user data for the view, make sure this code is in its own function so that you can call it again upon login.

**Update**

Call the getInfo() in viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear() instead. If that is too often, you can set a flag when a user logs in so that getInfo() is called only if it's a newly logged in user.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. ACL is set to public read, because I need users to have access to certain info about other users. I have got a function `getInfo()` which fetches the users data. I call it in the `viewDidLoad`. The view is obviously already loaded at this point form the previous user.

Comment: Your update worked perfectly. Now, I still have a second VC which shows a group of users in a table view. As long as the logged out and newly logged in user are in the same group there is no problem. If they aren’t however, there is. What I was trying to do, was setting a variable `userCheck = PFUser.currentUser()` in my `viewDidLoad()` and then comparing `userCheck` to `PFUser.currentUser` every time the `viewWillAppear`. My problem is the initialization. `var userCheck : PFUser` doesn’t work because it is not initialized at super.init call. `var userCheck = PFUser()` crashes the app instant